# Javascript detect divx web player

Tags: javascript, plugins, divx

Is there any simple way to detect via JavaScript if DivX Web Player is currently installed on the browser visiting my web page?

I'd need to play a video ONLY if DivX web player is installed properly. Otherwise I'd need to redirect my user to another page.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not sure, perhaps http://code.google.com/p/divxweb/wiki/JavascriptLibrary

Answer (score 1):

Check this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.navigator.plugins

But! First of all it doesn't work in IE. And how to check **is it enabled or not** I don't know, so when I have fighting with divx web player, I rejected ideas with plugins. I used **videolightbox** as a solution, becouse it's works greate even if divx is installed.